# How to access user data coming from Azure from everywhere in my Web Form App?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, azure

I have created a web form project on Microsoft Azure. Visual studio takes care of creating all the web forms for you. One of the web forms called UserInfo.aspx, in the back end of it there is a function that queries the user data from a domain controller on Azure as the following:

```
private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
private static string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientID"];
private static string appKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientSecret"];
private static string aadInstance = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AADInstance"];
private static string graphResourceId = "https://graph.windows.net";

public Task GetUserData()
        {
            return Task.Run(() =>
            {
                string tenantID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid").Value;
                string userObjectID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;
                try
                {
                    Uri servicePointUri = new Uri(graphResourceId);
                    Uri serviceRoot = new Uri(servicePointUri, tenantID);
                    ActiveDirectoryClient activeDirectoryClient = new ActiveDirectoryClient(serviceRoot,
                          async () => await GetTokenForApplication());

                    // use the token for querying the graph to get the user details
                    IUser user = activeDirectoryClient.Users
                        .Where(u => u.ObjectId.Equals(userObjectID))
                        .ExecuteAsync().Result.CurrentPage.ToList().First();

                    UserData.DataSource = new List<IUser> { user };
                    UserData.DataBind();
                }
                // if the above failed, the user needs to explicitly re-authenticate for the app to obtain the required token
                catch (AdalException)
                {
                    GetToken.Visible = true;
                }
                // if the above failed, the user needs to explicitly re-authenticate for the app to obtain the required token
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    ShowData.Visible = false;
                    GetToken.Visible = true;
                }
            });
        }

public async Task<string> GetTokenForApplication()
{
    string signedInUserID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
    string tenantID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid").Value;
    string userObjectID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;

    // get a token for the Graph without triggering any user interaction (from the cache, via multi-resource refresh token, etc)
    ClientCredential clientcred = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
    // initialize AuthenticationContext with the token cache of the currently signed in user, as kept in the app's EF DB
    AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(aadInstance + tenantID, new ADALTokenCache(signedInUserID));
    AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(graphResourceId, clientcred, new UserIdentifier(userObjectID, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId));
    return authenticationResult.AccessToken;
}
```

As you notice in GetUserData function, Visual studio is saving the user information inside the variable 'user' that has the type IUser.

'user' variable has properties that I want in it such as 'JobTitle' or 'city'. I want to be able at the beginning of my application to have an access to this 'user' variable and then use it ANYWHERE inside my project.

I tried to create a function that return IUser instead of 'Task' but it did not work. My intention is to use 'user' variable to prevent the user form accessing certain pages by checking the 'JobTitle' and I also want to use the attribute 'JobTitle' in my javascript files (front-end) to do extra validation.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you using MVC or Web Forms?

Comment: I am using Web Forms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we want to return the user Info, please have a try to change the function return type from Task to `Task <IUser>` or `Task<List<IUser>>`

```
public async Task<IUser> GetUserData()
    {  
             ...  // logic
           return user;
    }
```

Comment: I will try that

Comment: However, where is the perfect place to put that code.. so I can have an access to the user's properties and export it to javascript?

Comment: If we want it to be called everywhere, it is a good choice to put the C# code in the [WebApi](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api). Then we can call the webapi  by javascript via sending http request.

Comment: Got it, thank you @Tom. Can I get the group that the user belongs to from the returned object "user"?

Comment: Does the user has the group property? If yes we also can get it easily. If we want to get a group of users, we can change the return type to Task<List<IUser>> and use a list to store users and return the list.